# I need to send an email from a perl CGI script without using sendmail

Tags: perl, email

I need to send an email that contains html in a perl CGI script without using sendmail. Is there a easy way to do this?

Comment: Do you consider invoking the 'mail' command as using sendmail?  The mail command will call sendmail, of course, but I'd like to understand your restrictions.

Comment: sendmail will not work on the box that my script is being run from.

Answer (score 7):

The synopsis of [Email::Sender](http://p3rl.org/Email%3a%3aSender) shows how to send mail directly via SMTP.

Answer (score 2):

You must send HTML code? The standard Perl distribution comes with [Net::SMTP](http://perldoc.perl.org/Net/SMTP.html) which implements the SMTP protocol directly in Perl. This means you can send mail on systems that don't have the `sendmail` or `mail` commands implemented, or `sendmail` installed. I've used it for years without too many issues.

If you can download Perl modules, you should look at [Email::MIME](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email%3a%3aMIME). That allows you to send out MIME multipart email, and doesn't depend upon Sendmail. I haven't used this one all that much, but it isn't that difficult to use.

Comment: Email::MIME produces an email object, but does not send it.

Answer (score 1):

There are many many modules on the CPAN that will do mail sending for you.  http://search.cpan.org/

Comment: I was using MIME:Lite but that in turn uses sendmail.

Comment: @James: MIME::Lite uses sendmail *by default*, but this does not mean that sendmail is the only supported sending method. Note that the second example in the MIME::Lite docs is "Create a multipart message (i.e., one with attachments) *and send it SMTP*" (emphasis mine); per the comments in that example, providing the parameter "smtp" to the `send` method will use Net::SMTP to send the message.